# Integrating realm db with some data

Tags: android, realm, android-studio-2.3

I need to write realm data base using realm studio or realm browser, then integrate this file into android studio to start app with new datas, any solutions how to do it?

Comment: Try This blog it's very simple and good : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via JSON or create a app and populate it with data into a database and then extract that database and include it in the app.

You can read more about the second method here https://hackernoon.com/realm-for-android-pre-populating-from-json-and-extracting-the-database-8709a2f8db18